# cmake project involving UseLATEX.cmake builds but fails to create output PDF. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: latex, cmake

In **manual** folder on Ubuntu 22.04 I have files **manual.tex, A.tex, B.tex, C.tex, D.tex** (the chapters), **UseLATEX.cmake**, and **CMakeLists.txt**.

CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project ( manual NONE)
SET(LATEX_OUTPUT_PATH /home/username/manual_out)

INCLUDE(UseLATEX.cmake)

ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT(manual.tex 
INPUTS A.tex B.tex C.tex D.tex 
IMAGE_DIRS images 
BIBFILES bibliography.bib
USE_INDEX)
```

script to recreate

```
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
make
```

error output

```
...
Output written on manual.pdf (1 page, 196553 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 63 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 37 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


CMake Error at /home/username/manual/UseLATEX.cmake:523 (message):
  Executed LaTeX, but LaTeX returned an error.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/manual/UseLATEX.cmake:2067 (latex_execute_latex)


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/manual_pdf.dir/build.make:85: /home/username/manual_out/manual.pdf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:252: CMakeFiles/manual_pdf.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by including the style file 'IEEEbib.bst' on the same line as 'bibliography.bib' and removing USE_INDEX.

Corrected CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project ( manual NONE)
SET(LATEX_OUTPUT_PATH /home/username/manual_out)

INCLUDE(UseLATEX.cmake)

ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT(manual.tex 
INPUTS A.tex B.tex C.tex D.tex 
IMAGE_DIRS images 
BIBFILES bibliography.bib IEEEbib.bst)
```

As it turned out this was Biblatex.  To use Biblatex with biber backend and modernize, I used this reference [https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee].  Unfortunately, other references from IEEE seemed to create compatibility issues which I did not fully understand.